# How bad is to have a lot of $(function(){}); in code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to an engine we have a template that puts a lot of that functions in code(for blocks with empty functionality):

```
    $(function(){
        // Code here
    });
```

Does it influence memory/speed?

Comment: Give it a play with http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have a very slight impact on both speed (the browser will need to create a function object, which has a small overhead), and also on memory (a reference to the function will get stored by jQuery, which means the function object will be retained in memory even though it doesn't do anything).

However neither of these things should really affect the performance of your page unless you have thousands of them, a bigger problem is that it will make your code messy and harder to read!

As pointed out in the comments, it also increases the size of your page, which will increase load time.

Comment: It also makes the files unnecessarily bigger, which means higher data traffic

Comment: dont really agree to @Markai in that point - (re)using for example JQuery functions to perform a certain action means you do not have to right the code yourself. so if you have allot of these $() function where you really need them, you will not have to define it over again. As long as you have hardware acceleration and dont get too big, you wont have to care about that issue... So it always depends on what alternatives you have

Comment: @Max Burnaye of course having a lot of empty functions increases the file size? How should it not?

Comment: @Markai okay, what he writes and what the code says is controversal... i retreat you win

Comment: @Max Burnaye the question also said *for blocks with empty functionality* and i think this commentary comes from the template. If there is code in there, the whole question is pointless

Comment: I am not sure that jQuery will retain anonymous functions, but I have asked a question about this explicitely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910702/will-jquery-retain-an-anonymous-on-ready-listener